# How to access a XAML element in a nested frame in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, windows-runtime

I am trying to access the contents of a RichEditBox contained inside a XAML page that is itself contained inside another page that is invoked from my App.xaml.cs file. The following explains the situation.

My App.xaml.cs file can access elements in my MainPage.xaml with the following:

```
var MainPage = Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Content as MainPage;
```

My MainPage.xaml file includes the following:

```
<Frame x:Name="RootFrame" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
```

Which gets linked to an instance Editor.xaml / Editor.xaml.cs.

From MainPage.xaml.cs I can access the RichEditBox named `EditorBox` inside Editor.xaml with the following:

```
var Editor = RootFrame.Content as Editor;
string textboxtext;
Editor.EditorBox.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, out textboxtext);
```

What I would like to do is to get the contents of this RichEditBox (`EditorBox`) from the App.xaml.cs file so that I can save them when the app suspends.

I have tried combining the commands above in ways like the following:

```
var MainPage = Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Content as MainPage;
var Editor = MainPage.RootFrame.Content as Editor;
string textboxtext;
Editor.EditorBox.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, out textboxtext);
```

But this doesn't work. When the app tries to suspend, it gets a `System.NullReferenceException` on the line:

```
var Editor = MainPage.RootFrame.Content as Editor;
```

How can I resolve this problem and retrieve the contents of the RichEditBox from my App.xaml.cs file?